# save button in my merchant's PayPal account

Tags: paypal

I have created my own Buy Now button where the amount is entered in a text box on my web page by users. My Paypal id hard written in this form. Is it possible to save this button in my own Merchant account?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Standard Integration Wizard](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/standard-integration) to create your button.  Step 3, I think it is, in the process asks if you want to manage inventory for the button.  If you click into the details for that one you'll see it has a check box for "Save to my PayPal account" which should be checked by default.

When you create a button with this option it gets saved in your button manager and can be adjusted in the future if you want.

If you're familiar with web service API's you can also use the [Button Manager API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrOverview/) to generate buttons that are saved in your account.  If you're working with PHP my [class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) will make that very simple for you.

Comment: My own Buy Now button has <input type="text" name="amount" class=boxmedium maxlength="50"> a box where user types how much he want to pay rather then an assigned price like in standard Buy Now button

Comment: Right.  A hosted button would look the same way on the site, but the fields you're seeing wouldn't be included with the button code.  Instead, it would be limited to just a few fields, one of which is a hosted_button_id, and that's the ID that PayPal uses to store and pull all the details about it.

Comment: So where in my PayPal page can I host my code for my own designed button and refer to it using the hosted_button_id field?

Comment: PayPal hosts the code for you.  That's where the term hosted button comes from.  You can create new buttons from within the Button Manager in your PayPal profile, and you can choose your own graphic during that process.